# Is it really 11 steps to derivate this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have tried to solve this but haven't found any good solution. I'm trying to find the way from P to $ P_y$ and from Q to $ Q_x $ . When using Wolfram Alpha it suggests an 11 step-solution which I don't find trustworthy as the most efficient way.

I have used the quotient rule but always get stuck. Trying to use a partial derivative approach and consider x as a constant and use the quotient rule to get $ P_y $.

Differentiate $$P=\frac{x - y}{x(x+y)}$$ with respect to $y$ implies $$P_y=\frac {-2}{(x+y)^2}$$

Differentiate $$Q=\frac{y-x }{y(x+y)}$$ with respect to $x$ implies $$Q_x=\frac {-2}{(x+y)^2}$$

How can I prove this?

Comment: "I have tried to solve this equation" --> which equation?

Comment: Edited, sorry for my English skills.

Comment: Still, the equation which you want to solve is not displayed! Presumably a differential equation - where is it?

Comment: @Andreas presumably he's just trying to differentiate!

Comment: @Andreas I'm trying to find the way from P to $ P_y$ and from Q to $ Q_x $ .

Comment: alright- that makes it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative forms with obvious derivatives are
$$
P=\frac{2x-(x+y)}{x(x+y)}=\frac2{x+y}-\frac{1}{x}
\\
Q=\frac{2y-(x+y)}{y(x+y)}=\frac2{x+y}-\frac1y
$$
so that you can read off directly the complete differentials in
$$
P\,dx+Q\,dy=2\frac{d(x+y)}{x+y}-\frac{dx}x-\frac{dy}y
$$

Comment: Where does the "2" come from?

Comment: Elementary, $x-y=2x-(x+y)$. You could also call it partial fraction decomposition.